# Validation Not Working on Nested Objects in Play Framework 2

Tags: java, validation, playframework, annotations, playframework-2.0

I'm using the Constraint annotations for validating my objects in Play! framework 2.  It works fine for top level objects, but not nested ones.  How do I get my nested object validation annotations to work?

Event: The top level object I am saving.

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Required
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Option> options;

    ...
}
```

Option: The nested object.  Its not validating the name property.

```
@Entity
public class Option {

    @Required
    public String name;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not familiar with Play, but it looks very close to javax.validation, in which you'd need to put `@Valid` on your `options` field to tell the validator to descend into that relationship. Play has an [@Valid](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2/play/data/validation/Valid.html) of its own, so I'd give that a shot.

**Update:** As OP pointed out, the above is Play 1.0. Instead, per the [Play 2.0 docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms), it uses Spring data binding and JSR-303 under the hood, so how about using the [javax.validation @Valid](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/Valid.html) annotation on it? Maybe Play 1.0 had a home-made validation framework and they decided to move to javax.validation in 2.0? That would explain why several validation annotations seem to have disappeared in the 2.0 API.

Comment: I believe that's a Play 1 annotation, not 2.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Updated my answer. Give that a try.